# Android SQLite select one row from table where qualifier is in other table.

Tags: android, sqlite, select, join, union

Hi all trying to put together a better SQLite SELECT query.  I've looked through SO and other spots on the interweb but haven't had any luck with this problem yet, so here goes:

I have two tables in SQLite: tblMessage and tblCategory.  Users can disable individual messages, or disable whole categories of messages.

tblMessage looks something like this (simplified):

> INT _id, INT categoryId, TEXT messageText, BOOL messageHidden

tblCategory looks something like this (simplified):

> INT_id, TEXT categoryName, BOOL categoryHidden

As it stands right now, I am picking a message from the first table with...

> SELECT * FROM tblMessage ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1 WHERE msgHidden = "F"

... and then opening another cursor to tblCategory to grab the info of the matching categoryId.

> SELECT * FROM tblCategory WHERE _id = (categoryID from first select)

I then proceed to check if the categoryHidden is true (in code), in which case I go back and do the whole message selection again until I get one that is not from a hidden category.

This all works properly, however I suspect I can eliminate results from these hidden categories in the initial message SELECT statement and dispense with the comparison in code. I'm looking into JOINS and UNIONS but I'm fairly new to SQL and haven't found quite what I'm after.

This is something very simple right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one query

```
SELECT tblMessage._id, tblMessage.categoryId, tblMessage.messageText,  
       tblMessage.messageHidden FROM tblMessage, tblCategory   
       WHERE tblMessage.categoryId = tblCategory._id AND tblMessage.messageHidden="F"
       AND tblCategory.categoryHidden = "F" ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That's the one I needed all right.  Although 'tblCategory = "F"' needed to be 'tblCategory.categoryHidden = "F"'  Thanks for your quick response!