# How to use query in android sqlite database

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

In my application previously I was retrieving data from table which is in sqlite database.
So I was using following way to get the data:

```
cursor = database.query("CIRCLE", new String[] { "CIRCLE_ID",
            "ZONE_ID", "NAME" }, "ZONE_ID = " + id, null, null, null, "NAME");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            circleLists.add(new CircleList(cursor.getInt(0), cursor
                    .getInt(1), cursor.getString(2)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Now I need to retrieve data from one table whose id is matched by id of some other table and where condition match id(after getting data) from some other table.
I have the SQl query. I don't know how to implement this query in **cursor = database.query(...)**

The SQL query is:

```
select d.division_id, d.name from division d, division_circle_assoc dca
where d.division_id = dca.division_id and dca.circle_id = 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056172/android-sqlite-select-one-row-from-table-where-qualifier-is-in-other-table. check this might help

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor = database.rawQuery("select d.division_id, d.name from division d, division_circle_assoc dca
where d.division_id = dca.division_id and dca.circle_id = 1", null);
```

and

```
String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_D_ID, KEY_NAME};
             String whereClause = KEY_D_ID + "=" + KEY_DD_ID +" AND "+ KEY_C_ID +"= 1";
             Cursor cursor = mDb.query(true, DIVISION + " INNER JOIN "+ DIVISION_CIRCLE, columns, whereClause, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I know we can use rawQuery... but is there any way to use database.query(...) to retrieve data...???